# pd.DataFrame.from_dict() does not give an expected result

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, word-count

I'm new to Python programming. I want to get the word count for each word in this Wikipedia dataset (`people_wiki.csv`). I am able to get each word and it's occurrence as a dictionary but I'm not able to split the dictionary key-value pair into separate columns. I've tried several methods (from_dict, from_records, to_frame, pivot_table, e.t.c) Is this something doable in python. I will appreciate any help.

Samle dataset:

```
URI                                           name             text

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/George_Clooney>  George Clooney   'george timothy clooney born may 6 1961 is an american actor writer producer director and activist he has received three golden globe awards for his work as an actor and two academy awards one for acting and the other for producingclooney made his...'
```

I've tried:

```
clooney_word_count_table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(clooney['word_count'], orient='index', columns=['word','count']
```

I've also tried:

```
clooney['word_count'].to_frame()
```

This is my code:

```
people = pd.read_csv("people_wiki.csv")
clooney = people[people['name'] == 'George Clooney']

from collections import Counter
clooney['word_count']= clooney['text'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split(' ')))

clooney_word_count_table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(clooney['word_count'], orient='index', columns=['word','count']
clooney _word_count_table
```

Output:

```
       word_count
35817   {'george': 1, 'timothy': 1, 'clooney': 9, 'ii': ...
```

I expect to get an output dataframe with 2 columns from clooney_word_count_table:

```
word      count
normalize  1
george     3
combat     1
producer   2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `clooney` is a DataFrame (containing one row with index 35817), so `clooney['word_count']` is a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#series) containing one value (your count dictionary) at index 35817.

`DataFrame.from_dict` then treats this series as equivalent to `{35817: {'george': 1,...}` which is what's giving you the confusing result.

Adapting this to your example, and assuming that you're going to want to produce a combined word count across many entries:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

# Load the wikipedia entries and select the ones we care about
people = pd.read_csv("people_wiki.csv")
people_to_process = people[people['name'] == 'George Clooney']

# Compute the counts for these entries
counts = Counter()
people_to_process['text'].apply(lambda text: counts.update(text.split(' ')))

# Transform the counter into a DataFrame
count_table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counts, orient='index', columns=['count'])
count_table
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for but the code is still throwing some error. (1). c.update gives a word_count of 0. (2). from_dict gives: TypeError: from_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'.

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, but I don't understand the problems you're seeing. I'll try adding a complete solution for your problem as I understand it!